# Must supply a valid URL Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Вот мой код:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, container, false);
    //Button fragbut = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragbut);
    listView4 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView999);
    textView4 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_import, R.id.textView3, titleList);
    newThread newThread1 = new newThread();
    newThread1.execute();

    try {
        final HashMap<String,String> hashMap = newThread1.get();
        for (Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet())
        {
            titleList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
        }

        listView4.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView4.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Parsetext parsetext = new Parsetext();
                parsetext.execute(hashMap.get(titleList.get(position)));
                try {
                    textView4.setText(parsetext.get());
                   // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                   // startActivity(intent);
                    listView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return rootView;

}
    // fragbut.setOnClickListener(this);

    // ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
    //  parseTitle.execute();


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {

        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

int translateIdToIndex(int id) {
    int index = -1;

    return index;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    int buttonIndex = translateIdToIndex(v.getId());

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(buttonIndex),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public interface OnSelectedButtonListener {
    void onButtonSelected(int buttonIndex);
}

class Parsetext extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String str = " ";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            Elements element = doc.select(".news_content");
            str = element.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }
}

class newThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String,String>> {

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String,String> doInBackground(Void... params) {


        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://gapp.az/").get();
            content = doc.select(".feed_desc");
            titleList.clear();
            for (Element contents : content) {
                Elements contents1 = contents.select("a[href]");
                hashMap.put(contents.text(),contents1.attr("abs:href"));
                titleList.add(contents.text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:72)
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:36)
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
>                                                                                   at com.example.adm.lifehacker.fragment.FragmentImport$Parsetext.doInBackground(FragmentImport.java:195)
>                                                                                   at com.example.adm.lifehacker.fragment.FragmentImport$Parsetext.doInBackground(FragmentImport.java:190)

Заголовки статей нормально загружаются. Проблема в том что не могу определить ссылку нажатой статьи

И еще в `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();`  `params[0]`пустой

Comment: выведите в лог, какая именно ссылка не является валидной

Comment: У вас, видать, относительная ссылка получается и надо домен к ней спереди подставить